# Draw 16 players into 4 groups where no one comes from same earlier group

Tags: excel, vba

I got between 16 and 40 players in groups of 4/5 players. meaning 4 to 10 groups.

I want to draw top16 (i got this list already formatted as:)

```
Name | Former Group (Ex. With 4 Groups)
Player1  | 1
Player2  | 2
Player3  | 3
Player4  | 4
Player5  | 4
Player6  | 3
Player7  | 2
Player8  | 1
Player9  | 2
Player10 | 1
Player11 | 3
Player12 | 4
Player13 | 1
Player14 | 2
Player15 | 4
Player16 | 3
```

This list i want to put into 4 Groups with a click of a button. Where no one comes from the same earlier group. This group is listed with players getting 1st in their former group first and then 2nd place and so on. So if its 10 groups of 4 my list could look like. As its 10 1st places and 6 2nd places in.

```
    Name | Former Group (Ex. With 10 Groups)
Player1  | 1
Player2  | 2
Player3  | 3
Player4  | 4
Player5  | 5
Player6  | 6
Player7  | 7
Player8  | 8
Player9  | 9
Player10 | 10
Player11 | 3
Player12 | 4
Player13 | 7
Player14 | 5
Player15 | 9
Player16 | 1
```

I want to draw these top16 players into 4 new groups where they dont come into a group with a player they already played in the first round.

So i thought i would create a function and call that on a button click.

onClick i want to collect these players from

AA6 to AA21 (is there name)
 AB6 to AB21 (is there former group number)

run them thru my function.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton11_Click()

    ReDim playerNames(0 To 16) As String
    ReDim playerGroups(0 To 16) As Integer

    For i = 1 To 16
    playerNames(i) = Cells(i + 5, 27).Value
    playerGroups(i) = Cells(i + 5, 28).Value
    Next i


  Dim txt As String
  Dim txt2 As String
  Dim ii As Long


  For ii = LBound(playerNames) To UBound(playerNames)
    txt = txt & playerNames(ii) & vbCrLf
    txt2 = txt2 & playerGroups(ii) & vbCrLf
  Next ii

  MsgBox txt + txt2


End Sub
```

How can i create a logic that never gives me groups where players come from the same group ?

and then i want to past these into

```
AC6->AC9 (GroupA)
AD6->AD9 (GroupB)
AE6->AE9 (GroupC)
AF6->AF9 (GroupD)
```

Comment: Have you looke don here for "combination" for example?

Comment: Let me see if I understand the question: You are taking the top 16 players, regardless of the previous number of groups, and you want to place them into 4 groups, avoiding putting them into groups with the same people from previous groups. Correct? So in your example with 10 previous groups, players 1 and 2 could be together since they were in different groups, but players 3 and 11 could not since they were both in group 3? One way would be to randomize the groups, check for repeat pairings, then recreate them until you don't have repeats.

Comment: @DavidP Correct, and yes i could just try again and again. But im afraid it could cause a really long loop no ?

Comment: @SonnyHansen Long is relative. Doing something a million times sounds like a lot, but it might only take a few seconds. I doubt it would take near that many tries. Another thing you can do to be sure is to put a limit on the number of tries. Add a variable that counts up the number of times the loop has run and if it hits your predefined limit, break out of the loop.